# Lock file when opening, unlock it when closing it

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way to have ST check if a file is already opened by another user (on a Linux system) and if so not open the file and notify the user?

I guess this involves ST locking the file upon opening it and unlocking it when the file is closed.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I miss this feature too, from vim iirc